# Process builder failure after adding new values to multiselect picklist field

Tags: process-builder

Salesforce newbie here... Two new values were added to an existing multiselect picklist field (e.g., 2 new possible roles for a contact), and now the process that gets triggered whenever a new contact is added or updated fails if the user chooses any of the new values. The immediate action checks against contact id (field reference) and role (field reference). I decided to change the role check from field reference to multi select, and noticed that the new values are not among the possible choices... Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you added new picklist values  to the record type concerned ?

Comment: Yes we did. This is the resulting error from process builder: "INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST: Role to Program: bad value for restricted picklist field: Group of Five"

Comment: As per error it is related to recordtype context only.ifyou are sure new values are added in recordtype   then i would like to know  how you are giving picklist values in process builder.  Is it hardcoded?   Then make sure  it is exact same as developername of picklist

Comment: And i would like to add that there can be multiple record type  make sure new values  are added wherever necessary  for all recordtype

Comment: ['INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST' error from Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8mBKSAZ)

Comment: Thanks! All the record types have the new values. And in the process builder it is done via a field reference. If I tried to do it via a multiselect pickfield, then none of the new variables are available to be chosen...